# Similar matches/Partial String Matches of Two Datasets in R

Tags: r, string, text

I have a dataset that has well over 100,000 observations (`df1`). There is an open text field to enter your name: `HCP_Names`

```
df1$HCP_Names<- c("Ahmaaad M", "Ahmad Mobin", "Ahmed Mobin" "Dr.Ahmad" "A.Mobin" , "Ahmad.M" , "AhmadMursalinM", "MursalinModin", "Mobin", "Ahmad", "Vince", "Jim Smith" , "Mario Gomez", "Lisa Robin", "Brown Jim")
```

Basically for `HCP_Names` there could be a lot of variation

I have a list of names about 4,000 (`df2$ListofNames`) that I would like to check to see if it can be found in df1$HCP_Names. * Please note that the two list are not equal!

```
df2$ListofNames<- c("Ahmad Mobin" , "Tanya Singh", "Jim Brown", "Vince Johnson", "Stacey Seguin", "Tim Black", "Ron James", "Lisa Robin")
```

I would like to generate a separate dataframe that tells me the probability of the elements in df2$ListofNames matches with df1$HCP_Names.  Afterwards the plan is for me to manual check the highly likely matches to see if in fact they are a match (or not).

PS. notice since df1$HCP_Names was an open text field someone in theory could enter their Last Name first and then their First Name Last. However, df2$ListofNames has one unique entry for each individual

Comment: check out the package RecordLinkage which provides functions for linking individuals between dataframes.

Comment: I have, I am still stuck. If you can provide me with a code that will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I found an answer that works for me:

I combined the names from `df1$HCP_Names` with the names from `df2$ListofNames` into one column `Name_List1` and ran the following code:

```
require(RecordLinkage)
rec.pair<- compare.dedup(Names_List1,
                         strcmp = 1,
                         strcmpfun=levenshteinSim)
```

It produces this output:

id1 id2 HCP_Names is_match

907 4471 0.962    NA

I then I manually check each "high probable" matches.

Hope this helps someone out there!